# Codeigniter - Unknown Column In Where Clause

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have function model i used codeigniter version 2.1.3

```
function get_last_ten_absen($limit, $offset) {
  $this->db->select('absen.id_absen, absen.tanggal, absen.nis, siswa.nama, kelas.kelas, absen.absen');
  $this->db->from('absen, siswa, kelas, semester');
  $this->db->where('siswa.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas');
  $this->db->where('absen.nis=siswa.nis');
  $this->db->where('semester.id_semester=absen.id_semester');
  $this->db->order_by('absen.tanggal', 'desc');
  $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

I get error

```
A Database Error Occurred    
Error Number: 1054    
Unknown column 'siswa.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas' in 'where clause'
```

Please help me.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

That's not how db->where() works anyway...

```
$this->db->where('siswa.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas');
```

Should be:

```
$this->db->where('siswa.id_kelas', 'kelas.id_kelas');
```

Comment: This is the same answer as stormdrain..., besides it's incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Your `where` is incorrect - it accepts an array not a string:

```
$this->db->where('siswa.id_kelas=kelas.id_kelas');
```

should be

```
$this->db->where('siswa.id_kelas', 'kelas.id_kelas');
```

As always, [the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) can be quite helpful...

Comment: Yeah, it *can* be quite helpful. Look at **4) Custom string**. That shows you that the above is a valid use of `where`. The only problem is that one of those columns doesn't exist in the database. What you are suggesting changes the query completely. I don't understand why people are upvoting. Should be downvoted.

Comment: Is it still valid without the indicated single quotes?

Comment: @Mischa So you tried the method stormdrain just mentioned and that didn't work either then ? Edit : besides, in what way does it change the query ? In both cases you're referring to a column in a different table, what makes you think the equal sign you type is different from the generated one?

Comment: @Daneo - I didn't try, because I know it's wrong. What he is suggesting turns your where clause into: `WHERE siswa.id_kelas = 'kelas.id_kelas'` while it should be `WHERE siswa.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas`.

Comment: "$this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks."

Comment: @drieanto - no it doesn't. It just doesn't give an error, but it doesn't do what you expect!!!

Comment: @Mischa Firstly, it does not change the query completely -- it yields the same query. Secondly, no need to be editorializing...you don't agree, downvote and move on. Thirdly, it works so... ;)

Comment: @stormdrain, it doesn't yield the same query. Yours yields `WHERE siswa.id_kelas = 'kelas.id_kelas'` while it should be `WHERE siswa.id_kelas = kelas.id_kelas`. The only problem is that `kelas.id_kelas` apparently doesn't exist.